# Escolher a certa entre muitas respostas

Tags: debate, respostas, resposta-aceita

Recentemente fiz [uma pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/250848/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-os-operadores-de-compara%C3%A7%C3%A3o-no-oracle/250862#250862) e a mesma obteve um alto numero de resposta, as quais boa parte são complementares. Cada uma delas levanta e expõe um ponto e são todos excelentes e esclarecedoras.

Como determinar qual a correta? Quais critérios utilizar?

Comment: Escolha a pergunta que esclareceu sua dúvida de uma forma melhor que as outras. Dica: Eu costumo esperar 24 horas antes de marcar o aceito em uma resposta de alguma pergunta minha, assim da tempo de mais usuários responderem.

Comment: Obrigado, vou esperar. Fiquei muito feliz com tanto engajamento e com o tanto que aprendi.

Comment: Quando há "conflito" sobre a resposta "que esclareceu sua dúvida de uma forma melhor que as outras", eu tendo a ir para aquela que contém mais informações/informações mais aprofundadas, de modo que o futuro leitor receba como primeira proposta de resolução aquela na qual ele pode se aprofundar